# Stop Rigidbody Movement/Rotation instantly after collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want my sphere to jump from one position to another but don't want it to translate afterward. I can't figure out how to do that. Here's my code:

```
void Update()
{
    if (!thrown && ((Input.touchCount > 0 
    && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended) 
    || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)))
    {
        rb.isKinematic = false;
        rb.AddForce(new Vector3(0.0f, 15.0f, 5.0f) );
        thrown = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "translate"? Do you have more code somewhere translating the ball? If so, you should add it

Comment: No,but AddForce is doing the translation.

Comment: If I understood well, you want the ball to stop right after it touches the ground?

Comment: Yes,that's what I exactly want.

Comment: If both the ball and the ground have `Colliders`, you could detect collision between the two and freeze the ball's `Transform`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many ways to make Object stop immediately after collison. I will give you two ways:

**Method 1**:

Set the *velocity* of the `Rigidbody` to `0` when you detect a collison.

If the object is also rotating, set the `angularVelocity` to `0` too.

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        Rigidbody rbdy = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        //Stop Moving/Translating
        rbdy.velocity = Vector3.zero;

        //Stop rotating
        rbdy.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
    }
}
```

**Method 2**:

Use *Physic Material* to control the amount of friction during collison.

Go to *Assets* > *Create* > *Physic Material*

Change the *Bounciness* to `0`.

Change the *Dynamic* and *Static Frictions* to values equals or more than `1`.

[image]

Then attach it to the `Material` slot on your `Collider`.

[image]